# Subquery returned more than 1 value.This is not permitted when the subquery is used as an expression.How to fix?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I run the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
    cusip, 
    symbol,
    CASE WHEN (U1 = 0 OR U2 = 0 OR U3 = 0) 
              THEN 0 END Universe_Flag,
    CASE WHEN (S1 = 'STOP' OR S2 = 'STOP' OR S3 = 'STOP') 
              THEN 'STOP' 
         WHEN (S1 = 'ACTIVE' OR S2 = 'ACTIVE' OR S3 = 'ACTIVE') 
              THEN 'ACTIVE' `enter code here`
    END Status

FROM (
    SELECT
        b.cusip,
        b.symbol,
        (SELECT UNIVERSE FROM sec_master m WHERE m.CUSIP = b.cusip) U1,
        (SELECT UNIVERSE FROM sec_master m WHERE m.SEDOL = b.cusip) U2,
        (SELECT UNIVERSE FROM sec_master m WHERE m.CINS  = b.cusip) U3,
        (SELECT SEC_STATUS FROM sec_master m WHERE m.CUSIP = b.cusip) S1,
        (SELECT SEC_STATUS FROM sec_master m WHERE m.SEDOL = b.cusip) S2,
        (SELECT SEC_STATUS FROM sec_master m WHERE m.CINS  = b.cusip) S3
    FROM (
        SELECT 
             e.cusip,
             e.symbol 
        FROM benchmark e 
        WHERE e.date > DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month,0,GETDATE()), 0)
    ) b

    LEFT JOIN sec_master x1 
        ON x1.CUSIP = b.cusip 
            AND x1.SEC_STATUS = 'ACTIVE' 
            AND x1.UNIVERSE = 1

    LEFT JOIN sec_master x2 
        ON x2.SEDOL = b.cusip 
            AND x2.SEC_STATUS = 'ACTIVE' 
            AND x2.UNIVERSE = 1

    LEFT JOIN sec_master x3 
        ON x3.CINS  = b.cusip 
            AND x3.SEC_STATUS = 'ACTIVE' 
            AND x3.UNIVERSE = 1

    WHERE x1.SEC_ID IS NULL 
        AND x2.SEC_ID IS NULL 
        AND x3.SEC_ID IS NULL
) X
```

But return the following error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 69 Subquery returned more than 1
>   value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows `=`, `!=`, `<`, `<=`, > `>`, `>=` or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: My guess is that your subqueries on the `sec_master` table are the cuprit.  By the way, are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: You should use joins instead all those nasty subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

One of your `SELECT ... FROM sec_master m WHERE ...` return more than one row. You can use `TOP(1)` with `ORDER BY` clause or change predicates in `WHERE` clause to guarated get only one row.

Comment: How do you know that the logic is even correct if more than one record is being returned?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, you are right, in most case there are mistake

Comment: @RuslanK., thanks! It fixes the syntax problem, but we still need to modify it as it can hide some potential data problem.